# println, массив и NullPointerException

Tags: java

Не могу разобраться, почему после запуска программы выдает исключение *java.langNullPointerException* на метод `System.out.println();`

```
public class Mix4TestDrive {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        int count = 0;
        Mix4 [] m4a = new Mix4[20];
        int x = 0;

        while (x < 9) {
            m4a[x] = new Mix4();
            m4a[x].counter = m4a[x].counter + 1;
            count = count + 1;
            count = count + m4a[x].counter;
            x = x + 1;
        };

        System.out.println(count + " " + m4a[x].counter);
    }
}


public class Mix4 {
    int counter = 0;

    public int maybeNew(int index) {
        if (index < 5) {
            Mix4 m4 = new Mix4();
            m4.counter = m4.counter + 1;
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Исключение выдает именно на `m4a[x].counter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это ожидаемо.

После окончания работы цикла у вас `x==9`, а в массиве с индексом `9` лежит `null` так как в цикле были созданы элементы с индексами `0` до `8`.

`m4a[x]` возвращает `null` и доступ к полю `counter` генерирует `NullPointerException`.